# Swift/ Parse- how to create a Parse class with a LOG of sent push notifications?

Tags: swift, parsing, logging, push

I have a chat app, push notifications are already working. I want to create a log of sent push notifications to be able to show the user if the message was sent.
How can I do it?

I have a func to send push:

```
class func sendPushNotification(groupId: String, text: String) {
    let query = PFQuery(className: PF_MESSAGES_CLASS_NAME)
    query.whereKey(PF_MESSAGES_GROUPID, equalTo: groupId)
    query.whereKey(PF_MESSAGES_USER, notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser())
    query.includeKey(PF_MESSAGES_USER)

    query.limit = 1000

    let installationQuery = PFInstallation.query()
    installationQuery.whereKey(PF_INSTALLATION_USER, matchesKey: PF_MESSAGES_USER, inQuery: query)

    let push = PFPush()

    var badgeCount = 0
    let data = [
        "alert" : text,
        "badge" : ++badgeCount,
        "sounds" : "message.mp3"
    ]

    push.setQuery(installationQuery)
    push.setData(data as [NSObject : AnyObject])

    push.sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("sendPushNotification error")
        }
    }

}
```

Then I have a class to control the chat, it has a funct called sendMessage that calls in the end the funct: PushNotication.sendPushNotification(self.groupId, text: textPush)

Now I need to check if the push was sent and store it in a Parse class. I imagine it could be a class with columns: messageId, date the push was sent.

Comment: Show us what have you done, what did you think, provide more detail and not just asking **how can I do it**

Comment: sorry @Breek, just updated the post with more info